# Maturity of in-situ steel production conceptualization?

Tags: mining

While [MOXIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Oxygen_ISRU_Experiment) (Mars OXygen In situ resource utilization Experiment) looks like to be tested in an upcoming mission in real condition, do we know how would we produce steel in-situ (in terms of processing resources to steel artefacts)?

For example the company *planetary resources* focuses yet first on discovering resources, but is there already something like a steel mill or similar in design as well anywhere?